# Sparse, bootable Linux images?

Tags: backup, ext4, bootable, rescue, sparse-files

I've set up a new Linux workstation and would like to create a backup image in order to save time in case something breaks. This is the situation:

- Workstation: **512 GB** SSD, **12 GB** used, ext4 file system, may contain bad blocks
- Backup drive: **64 GB** USB flash drive

The backup image should be **bootable** for added flexibility and, importantly, *all programs, configurations, network settings (proxies, VPNs) etc. have to be preserved.*

As I understand, a **sparse**, file-based image is necessary, since the backup drive (and possibly also the replacement drive) is smaller than the source drive.

**What backup/cloning tool *understands file systems* and creates sparse, bootable images?**

AFAIK, `dd` just copies bit by bit and `ddrescue` can only sparsify blocks of zeros into metadata, but not unused space filled with random data. Some disk cleanup tools offer to fill unused space with zeros, but this usually takes many hours and I'm not sure if this is good practice for collapsing data (especially on an SSD).

I need a reliable, free, and easy solution as I don't have much expertise on file systems, partition structures, boot sectors etc.

Comment: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310) For the record, the other post is [on Super User](https://superuser.com/q/1567190/432690).

Comment: The question fits here as the solutions are Linux-specific. The decision to keep the original topic on Super User open was made with regard to the ongoing discussions and pending bounty.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to partition the backup drive, create the file system(s), and copy the files over using `cp -a` or rsync. Then install a bootloader on the drive.

Comment: How does the backup drive have to be partitioned, does it suffice to allocate the amount of space equivalent to the sparsified data? And installing the bootloader means simply copying over the first 446 Bytes to the new drive?

Comment: If the source drive has **multiple** partitions (I think there are 4 in total, something like *system + swap + LVM + LUKS*...it's just a standard LMDE4 installation), do I have to recreate **all** of them on the destination drive (albeit with less allocated space)? What if I just create a *single* ext4 partition and throw everything into it - will this cause problems when launching/running the backup?